# Accessing Google Drive Using Rclone & Rclone Browser

Tags: kubuntu, google-drive, rclone

I setup Rclone & Rclone Browser on my computer and everything works. The problem is, it is  very slow. It seems that my computer runs fine until I try to do something that requires the use of Dolphin. Dolphin is slow to load and navigate through. Also, if I am doing something on Chrome and I need to upload or download something and I have to browse to the location, it takes at lease 5 minutes for the box to pop up for me to do what I need to do. I would like to know if someone has any idea what could be going on and how to fix it. This is very frustrating. I am thinking that it is something to do with Rclone & Rclone Browser but I am not sure. I am using Rclone to access my files on Google Drive.  My other question is, how do I get my drive to mount automatically when my computer boots? I am using Kubuntu 20.4.

Comment: I have a script for loading at reboot.... `@reboot rclone mount --allow-other EODCrafter:Emby/TV /home/XXXXXX/TV
    @reboot rclone mount --allow-other EODCrafter:Emby/Videos /home/XXXXXX/Videos` Add this to a cron by issuing command `crontab -e`

Comment: Thank you for that. I will give that a try. Have you been experiencing slowness with Rclone as I mentioned that I have?

Comment: I got everything working now. It mounts at login and it runs a lot faster. I followed the instructions found at  https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-mount-your-google-drive-on-linux-with-google-drive-ocamlfuse & https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Automounting.

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" in the title. Instead post what you did as an answer. Self-answer are acceptable and highly encouraged. Thanks.